# Linq extract a count() value from a data object

Tags: linq, grouping, having

I have divAssignments that has potential multiple rows by rNI, an official id, according to a compound key of Indictment and booking numbers.

```
rNI    Booking  Indictment
12345  954445   10 12345
12345  954445   10 12346
12345  954445   10 12347
```

So ID has a count of 3 for a single booking number for this rni.

I get lost attempting to generate a count and a group by booking Number:

```
var moreThen = from dA in divAssignments
    select new { dA.rNI, IndictmentCount = dA.indictmentNumber.Count() };
```

Most of the examples are dealing with static int[] and don't seem to work in my case.

How do I get a group and then a count?  If I could put in a having that would be fantastic.

from a t-sql POV I'd use this:

```
Select rni, bookingNumber, count(*) IndictmentCount 
from divAssignments
group by rni, bookingNumber  
having count(*) > 0
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var query = from item in divAssignments
group item by item.rNI into grouping
select new
{
  Id = grouping.Key,
  Count = grouping.Count()
}
```

If you're interested in grouping by both the rNI and the booking number, I would change it to this:

```
var query = from item in divAssignements
   group item by new { item.rNI, a.Booking } into grouping
   select new
    {
      Id = grouping.Key,
      Count = grouping.Count
    };
```

OR

```
var query = from item in divAssignments
    group item by item into grouping
    select new
    {
      Id = grouping.Key,
      Count = grouping.Count()
    }
```

and implement IEquatable on the divAssignment object to support equality comparison.  The other option if you'd like is to write an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) instance to do the composite key comparison. Your query could then look like:

```
var query = 
  divAssignments
      .GroupBy(i => i, new MyCustomEqualityComparer())
      .Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Count = i.Count());
```

Comment: ooo, didn't see the composite key part. Getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =
    from dA in divAssignments
    group dA by new { dA.rNI, dA.bookingNumber };

foreach(var grp in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rNI={0}, bookingNumber={1} => Count={2}", grp.Key.rNI, grp.Key.bookingNumber, grp.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [Grouping operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754) in Linq you will get what you need.  The code:

```
  var count = from a in divAssignments
              group a by new { a.rNI, a.Booking } into b
              select b;
```

will return a collection of [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) objects.  This will give you the Key (in my example this will be an anonymous type with an rNI and a Booking property) and a collection of the divAssignments that match the key.

Answer (score 0):

Using Method syntax (much easier to read in my opinion):

First group the records, then select a new result for each group that contains the count.

```
var groups = divAssignments.GroupBy(d => new { d.rNI, d.Booking });
groups.Select(g=> new { g.Key.rNI, g.Key.Booking, IndictmentCount = g.Count() });
```